# Placing buttons on section headers is correct or not?

Tags: gui-design, usability, interaction-design, users

Is placing buttons on headers to the middle or extreme right side is correct or not? Could you please suggest me the appropriate place?

Example:
[image: Mockup]

Comment: Could you give us screenshots or mockups? I'm particularly interested in what do you mean by middle

Comment: After heading, bit middle or extreme right side can i place button?

Comment: I will send you the screenshot, can i get your mail id?

Comment: @Satya Edit your question and add a link to the image would be a better idea than to e-mail the image

Comment: Yeah, I meant it as Benny does, we have a nice image uploader feature.

Comment: Uploading a screenshot or mockup will also make clear what you mean by "header". We don't even know if this is a desktop application, mobile application, web application,... which makes it impossible te answer the question.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0hBKj1zY2egQWQ1X3dOc1F4OUk

Comment: Please see the depicted image on above link.

Answer (score 1):

You should not place action links in the header. You should attach a toolbar below the header. [Here](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxToolbar/index.shtml) you can see an example of a toolbar. Probably there will be more actions in the future, they should be grouped together at one place.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a simple action that affects all of the content that is represented by the header (like close or minimize the whole section), it would be fine to have a button at the extreme right. If it is actions that relates to the inner content it would be better to have it below the header in a toolbar or in context with the affected parts of the content.

Centered like you have in your example does not look good. An option is to have buttons  follow immediately after the header text, but it should still be related to the entire section, not just an action that affects parts of the content.

If done right, this can look good, and save vertical space on the page.